# A better way to check if a user were logged in and generate like dislike link

Tags: php

I have a script that takes some 500 rows from a table, and based on whether or not a user is logged in, generates a link to like or dislike the item.

The way it currently goes is like this:

```
//Select * from table;

//while(){
    if($userLogged)
    {
        echo $row['columnName'].' Like - Dislike';
    }else{
        echo $row['columnName'];
    }
}
```

This way, it checks if a user is logged at each and every row. `$userLogged` is set in a file that's included on this page. 
What would be a better way to do this instead of checking if a user were logged in inside the loop for each and every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting your question quiet well but I think you want to prevent condition each time you loop so you can check the condition first and than loop accordingly, example

```
if($userLogged) {
   while(condition) {

   }
} else {
   while(condition) {

   }
}
```

This way you don't have to check the condition inside the loop each time it loops

Comment: @Norman This will only work in this case, if you would've being deciding after fetching the records from the database than you had to go with the apprach you are currently using but for now, this is appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Use `sessions` here

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userLogged']))
{
    echo $row['columnName'].' Like - Dislike';
}else{
    echo $row['columnName'];
}
```

Comment: Yes I use session variables

Comment: @Norman than use loop inside the condition rather than outside the condition.

Answer (score 1):

If the code for the like and dislike is identical for each entry then you could do something like this.

```
$links =  ($userLogged)?"Like - Dislike":"";
while (condition){
    echo $row['columnName'].$links;
}
```